# Parenthesis in the data disappears when retrieved from excel using Selenium

Tags: excel, selenium-webdriver, data-driven

I used the following code to retrieve data from an excel file using Selenium WebDriver.
Data contains parenthesis in it, eg 'Golfo Dulce (Burica) Basin'
I want to paste it in a text box.

```
cValue = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(aCell+1).toString();   // cell value = Golfo Dulce (Burica) Basin
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='basinregioncountry']")).sendKeys(cValue);
```

It should retrieve 'Golfo Dulce (Burica) Basin' in the text box, but it displays 'Golfo Dulce Burica) Basin' .i.e. without opening parenthesis '('

I am not sure about the reason for this issue.
Anyone please help me on this.

Comment: Is that missing left bracket "(" OR left parenthesis ' ' ??

Comment: Never had that experience but going through docs can u try with `getCell(aCell+1).getStringCellValue()`?

Comment: @HelpingHands Oops, my bad. I meant the left bracket **(**.

Comment: @VivekSingh Thank you, friend. Your suggestion works fine with the code.

Comment: I have checked with data like yours but I am getting proper data with both (). please check that in excel bracket available proper?

Comment: While using FF, I faced this issue, but not when Chrome is used.
With the code correction, it's good to go now.